# Problems Spring Boot Jasperreports

Tags: spring-boot, jasper-reports

I'm trying to print with jasperreport and spring boot and I get the following error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ui.jasperreports.JasperReportsUtils
```

Reading other possible solutions suggest that you place

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The error also follows

Comment: Can you please add  POM.xml and java code ? Its impossible to answer questions  if not proper description and explanation is not given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that Spring Framework 5.0 [dropped support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x#removed-packages-classes-and-methods) for JasperReports. So the recommendation is to use version 4.3.x:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.19.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Note: the latest release of Spring Framework 4.3.x is [4.3.19.RELEASE](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.springframework%20AND%20a:spring-context-support%20AND%20v:4.3.*)